# How to overwrite file by changing json in it?

Tags: php, json, explode

I have a file `test.json` with json content like below -

```
{"user_id":3,"created_at":"2020-10-05 04:59:05","expire_user_id":"2,1"}
```

After reading above json I need to rewrite it like below.

```
{"user_id":2,"created_at":"2020-10-05 04:59:05","expire_user_id":"1"}
```

Another example. For below json -

```
{"user_id":3,"created_at":"2020-10-05 04:59:05","expire_user_id":"1"}
```

I need to make it like this -

```
{"user_id":1,"created_at":"2020-10-05 04:59:05"}
```

- Idea is to get first number from `expire_user_id` key and put it inside `user_id` key.
- If `expire_user_id` only has one element in it, then after removing that element, final json should not have that key in it.
- If there is no value inside `expire_user_id` key or `expire_user_id` key is not present then I want to rewrite it with empty string.

Below is what I have tried:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'));
if ((int) $data->user_id === $_SESSION['user_id']) {
    // rewrite the file with above logic.
    $content = isset($data->expire_user_id)
               ? json_encode(['user_id' => explode(',', $data->expire_user_id)[0], 'created_at' => (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
               : '';
    file_put_contents('test.json', $content);
}
```

I tried with above logic where I am using explode to get first value of comma separated string but confuse on how to put remaining string in `expire_user_id` key back or don't put it back if there is only one element in it. Above code doesn't work currently as confuse on how to put other things back in that json.

Comment: Why does `expire_user_id` have values like `"2,1"` to begin with, why is this not an _array_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following function (which you should rename to something more accurate). What it does is:

- `json_decode` the JSON,
- if `expire_user_id` is empty, return '{}' (empty object), otherwise:

  - `explode` `expire_user_id` into an array,
  - removes the first user ID using `array_shift`,
  - puts that it into `user_id`,
  - `unset`s `expire_user_id` if there are no more values in it,
  - joins it back with commas using `implode` otherwise,
- return the re-`json_encode`d data.

Code:

```
/**
 * @throws JsonException
 */
function alterJson(string $json): string
{
    $data = json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    if (empty($data->expire_user_id)) {
        return '{}';
    }

    $data->expire_user_id = explode(',', $data->expire_user_id);
    $data->user_id = array_shift($data->expire_user_id);

    if ($data->expire_user_id) {
        $data->expire_user_id = implode(',', $data->expire_user_id);
    } else {
        unset($data->expire_user_id);
    }

    return json_encode($data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
}
```

Usage:

```
$alteredJson = alterJson(<<<JSON
    {"user_id":3,"created_at":"2020-10-05 04:59:05","expire_user_id":"2,1"}
JSON);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5HESp)**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works fine after my initial testing. Also need to read about `array_shift` more.